# Does writing $x; mean anything in PHP?

Tags: php

To create a variable `x` with the value `12345` in PHP, we do the following:

```
<?php
    $x = 12345;
?>
```

But let's say that we wrote `$x;` without assigning it a value:

```
<?php
    $x;
?>
```

Does the above code causes anything to happen, or does PHP treat the above `$x;` as non-existent? for example is the above code effectively the same as the following empty code?:

```
<?php

?>
```

Comment: Nothing will happen, the variable will be undefined. It is the same as doing nothing.
In classes, you need to define variables and constants like:

`<?php
class test 
{
public string $x;
}`

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    $x;
?>
```

These line of code mean you just initialize a variable name called x.
but you doesn't assign value. But it will use some memory.

**You can check use of memory:**

```
<?php
$x;
echo memory_get_usage($x);
?>
```

**Your Empty CODE :**

```
<?php

?>
```

These line of code means you just initialize PHP script. But inside there is nothing actually. But it also use some memory.

**You can check use of memory:**

```
<?php
echo memory_get_usage();
?>
```

Hope you understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at what are the defined variables in the following script...

```
print_r(get_defined_vars());
$x;
print_r(get_defined_vars());
$x = 1;
print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

You can see that just using `$x;` doesn't define the variable, it only shows up after assigning it a value.  So effectively this is the same as doing nothing.

Also checking the opcodes being generated...

With `$x=1;` - `phpdbg -p* a.php`

```
function name: (null)
L1-4 {main}() /home/nigel/a.php - 0x7f2f36c8e000 + 3 ops
 L3    #0     EXT_STMT                                                                              
 L3    #1     ASSIGN                  $x                   1                                        
 L4    #2     RETURN<-1>              1
```

with `$x;` - `phpdbg -p* a.php`

```
function name: (null)
L1-4 {main}() /home/nigel/a.php - 0x7f5898079050 + 2 ops
 L4    #0     EXT_STMT                                                                              
 L4    #1     RETURN<-1>              1
```

So it looks as though no opcode is generated.

Comment: The variable is not defined, but more memory is required if I remove the comment is in front of $x; . https://3v4l.org/gSRvg

Comment: @jspit I had a look and if you store the memory usage before and after it shows the same difference in both cases.

Comment: I mean the absolute values for 8.1 //$x; -> 386280,  x; -> 386288, $x; $a; -> 386296. 8 bytes are apparently already reserved for each variable.